# How to split a file in bash by pattern if find a number

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text like:

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 2Vivamus dictum, justo mattis sollicitudin pretium, ante magna gravida ligula, 3a condimentum libero tortor sit amet lectus. Nulla congue mauris quis lobortis interdum. 4Integer eget ante mattis ante egestas suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet pellentesque risus, a luctus sem pellentesque nec. Curabitur vel luctus eros. Morbi id magna sit amet 5risus hendrerit porta. Praesent vitae sapien in nunc aliquet pharetra vitae sed lectus. Donec id magna magna. Phasellus eget rhoncus purus, vitae vestibulum nisl. 6Phasellus massa mi, ultricies id mi sit amet, tristique auctor mi.
```

I want to split the text by the numbers found, whatever; like:

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
2Vivamus dictum, justo mattis sollicitudin pretium, ante magna gravida ligula,
3a condimentum libero tortor sit amet lectus. Nulla congue mauris quis lobortis interdum.
...
```

In awk, I tried:

```
cat text | awk -F'/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/' '{for (i=1; i<= NF; i++) print $i}'
```

Where `-F` is `/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/`, a pattern used to test if is a number or not. But it`snt split the text.

If I change the pattern to any separator it works without problems, what is then the pattern that I should use for it?

Comment: You are matching a whole line that matches a positive/negative int value. Besides, you will have to check if the number matched is an incremented value of the previous match to avoid splitting on numbers inside valid chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 2Vivamus dictum, justo mattis sollicitudin pretium, ante magna gravida ligula, 3a condimentum libero tortor sit amet lectus. Nulla congue mauris quis lobortis interdum. 4Integer eget ante mattis ante egestas suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet pellentesque risus, a luctus sem pellentesque nec. Curabitur vel luctus eros. Morbi id magna sit amet 5risus hendrerit porta. Praesent vitae sapien in nunc aliquet pharetra vitae sed lectus. Donec id magna magna. Phasellus eget rhoncus purus, vitae vestibulum nisl. 6Phasellus massa mi, ultricies id mi sit amet, tristique auctor mi.
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[-+]?[0-9]+"}{printf "%s%s%s", $0, NR==1?"":"\n", RT}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
2Vivamus dictum, justo mattis sollicitudin pretium, ante magna gravida ligula, 
3a condimentum libero tortor sit amet lectus. Nulla congue mauris quis lobortis interdum. 
4Integer eget ante mattis ante egestas suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet pellentesque risus, a luctus sem pellentesque nec. Curabitur vel luctus eros. Morbi id magna sit amet 
5risus hendrerit porta. Praesent vitae sapien in nunc aliquet pharetra vitae sed lectus. Donec id magna magna. Phasellus eget rhoncus purus, vitae vestibulum nisl. 
6Phasellus massa mi, ultricies id mi sit amet, tristique auctor mi.
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is (`-` or `+`) repeated 0 or 1 time and digit repeated 1 or more time. Then for every row I `printf` content of said line followed by newline (only for non-first word) followed by found row terminator (`RT`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

This inserts a new line before every number, except the first, and also strips any whitespace before the new line.

```
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*([0-9]+)/\
\1/g; s/\n//'
```

You still have the problem of numbers within each line which are regular content. These will also have a new line prepended.

Answer (score 1):

absolutely no need for vendor proprietary solutions :

```
{m,n,g}awk '

(NF=NF)+gsub("[0-9]+[^0-9]+[.]? ","&\n")+gsub("[ \t]+\n",FS)' FS='\n' OFS= \
                                                              RS='^$' ORS=
```

_

```
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2Vivamus dictum, justo mattis sollicitudin pretium, ante magna gravida ligula,
3a condimentum libero tortor sit amet lectus. Nulla congue mauris quis lobortis interdum.
4Integer eget ante mattis ante egestas suscipit. Suspendisse imperdiet pellentesque risus, a luctus sem pellentesque nec. Curabitur vel luctus eros. Morbi id magna sit amet
5risus hendrerit porta. Praesent vitae sapien in nunc aliquet pharetra vitae sed lectus. Donec id magna magna. Phasellus eget rhoncus purus, vitae vestibulum nisl.
6Phasellus massa mi, ultricies id mi sit amet, tristique auctor mi.
```